# Start jira prompt Cannot find /root/Tools/tomcat_thank/bin/setclasspath.sh

Tags: jira

Problem Description:
I started jira after the installation was completed, suggesting the following exception. After some tossing, there is no solution. I am a new jira, I hope everyone can help me, thank you!

The Linux version is：
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

[jira2@iZ94fl301lgZ bin]$ ./start-jira.sh

To run JIRA in the foreground, start the server with start-jira.sh -fg
executing as current user
Cannot find /root/Tools/tomcat_thank/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you installed jira software as jira2 user.
With this user you have no access to /root.

Install jira to /opt as jira user and you can start jira.
Also use ./startup.sh instead start-jira.sh for starting jira.